# Issues with connection to portal after IP change of Target

Tags: iscsi

After changing the static ip of my Linux hosted iSCSI target I cannot connect anymore using the windows iSCSI initiator. I can ping both ways, all firewalls are off for troubleshooting and I restarted both machines.

Im lost, what files could I provide as logs for you all?

Comment: Is this an internal IP change or public? Could it be a port forwarding issue of some sort? I assume cache isn't a problem?

Comment: Both were internal IPs, from 192.168.1.250 to 10.10.10.250. Both the client and the host are on the same sub-net and can ping both ways. The physical connection is a single crossover cable, no router or switches.